# Git, how to pull new code and keep local changes? things like DB connection string, graphics, icons.. I don't want to put on source-code-host

Tags: git

I'm working with another developer and I don't want to put certain changes, code, graphics and config files, json files, on source-code-host. These changes are only needed when I want to upload the playstore. The are some changes in sourcecode files the other developer is working on.

What's the best thing to do? create a release branch and pull his changes to that branch? Could I do that without pushing to source-code-host, bitbucket in my case.

I'm a bit overwhelmed with git documentation, any help appreciated.

Comment: Just don't add your configuration files to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `.gitignore` file to do this. You can look up the format online. Basically, any file that matches the patterns inside it will never be added to the repo and thus never be pushed.

Comment: Yeah, but there are also some files that other developers do change. It's not just some files.